# Arduino Sim900 AT+SAPBR=1,1 --> Operation not allowed

Tags: arduino, at-command, sim900

I am using an Arduino Mega and a *Sim900* GSM/GPRS shield to make a request against an API.

During my initialization of my request the command `AT+SAPBR=1,1` is executed. Sometimes, when I execute the shield returns `OK`, sometimes the shield returns `"Operation not allowed"`, but I changed nothing compared to the working code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial(18, 19); 

void setup() {
 
  Serial1.begin(19200);
  delay(10000);  
  Serial1.print("AT+CPIN=1111\r");
  Serial1.flush(); 
  Serial1.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"\r");
  Serial1.flush(); 
  Serial1.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"my.apn.com\"\r");
  Serial1.flush(); 
  Serial1.print("AT+SAPBR=1,1\r");
  Serial1.flush(); 
// Here comes the error sometimes!

  Serial1.print("AT+SAPBR=2,1\r");
  Serial1.flush();
  Serial1.print("AT+HTTPINIT\r");
  Serial1.flush();
  Serial1.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1\r");
  Serial1.flush();
  Serial1.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"my-api.com/foo\"\r");
  Serial1.flush();
  Serial1.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"application/json\"\r");
  Serial1.flush();
  Serial1.print("AT+HTTPACTION=0\r");
  Serial1.flush();
  Serial1.print("AT+HTTPREAD\r");
  Serial1.flush();

// READ the Response

}

void loop() { 
  
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an introduction, we may say that `AT+SAPBR` command, as described in SIM900 [AT Commands guide](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.11.pdf), is used to configure and to activate the PDP context (data traffic).

In particular, the meaning of `AT+SAPBR=1,1` is

> **<cmd_type> = 1** - Open bearer
> **<cid> = 1** - Bearer profile identifier

From you code

```
delay(10000);  
Serial1.print("AT+CPIN=1111\r");
Serial1.flush(); 
Serial1.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"\r");
Serial1.flush(); 
Serial1.print("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"my.apn.com\"\r");
Serial1.flush(); 
Serial1.print("AT+SAPBR=1,1\r");
```

I see that you only wait for 10 seconds (the other commands usually return immediately.

---

For this reason, **the first solution** is increasing the delay (15 seconds should suffice).

The **second solution** involves querying the registration status. This can be done separately for GSM network (`AT+CREG?`) and for 2G data network (`AT+CGREG?`).

In both cases querying the command will result in an answer like

> **`+CGREG: <n>,<stat>`** (or `+CREG: <n>,<stat>`), where
> **<n>** is the setting performed through *set command*. It's used to enable unsolicited result messages. So, its value is usually `0`
> **<stat>** is the current registration status. It can have the following values
> **0** - Not registered. The GPRS service is disabled [...]
> **1** - Registered, home network [...]
> **2** - Not registered, but ME is currently trying to attach or searching an operator to register to. The GPRS service is enabled, but an allowable [...]
> **3** - Registration denied. The GPRS service is disabled [...]
> **4** - Unknown
> **5** - Registered, roaming

So, if you sure that the device has enough signal coverage, all you need is to provide `AT+CGREG?` command every second and wait for `+CGREG=0,1` (or `+CGREG=0,5` if you work in roaming).

Comment: Thanks but this is probably not the solution I am looking for. When I read the serial output of my code, the AT+CPIN=1111 returns initially +CREG: 2 and then +CREG: 1 a few seconds later. 

I interpret that as a signal that everything is right. After that, the remaining code is executed

Comment: @NiklasUllmann the command I mentioned, related to GPRS attach, is AT+C**G**REG. But as I wrote what you experience could be due also to other problems such as network coverage (if it is low registration might go continuously up and down).

Comment: A question: your device has simply stopped working or sometimes it could sitill happen that that command succeeds again? In the second case, doesn't _doubling_ the delay change anything?

Comment: Okay thanks, so i will start checking my coverage for a Data Connection too. And yes the program does not stop but it will also not Pick up the Network again.

Comment: I meant asking if sometimes it happens that that commands answers `OK` after the first time it failed, or if you are not able to activate the context anymore (always `ERROR` since then). In the first case, would you mind making me happy by changing the delay to 15s?

Comment: okay, will try it this evening and provide feedback.

Comment: Giving it more time to connect to a data network, works :)

Comment: Just a minor comment. You don't want to wait for `+CGREG=0,2` but for `+CGREG=0,1` instead (note the 1 instead of the 2). The number 2 means it is trying to connect but still haven't while the number 1 means that it is already connected. Basically any `registered` status (2 and 5) is what you are after.

Comment: @carlosV2 You are absolutely right. I perfectly knew it, but I apologize for this typo that actually invalidated my answer for such a long time.